# How to not watch a file for changes in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2, sbt-buildinfo

On a Play Framework 2.2 project that is using [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) to create a `BuildInfo.scala` file when the project is compiled, how can `build.sbt` be configured so that Play Framework won't watch the `BuildInfo.scala` file for changes, and won't restart the server if that file changes?

For instance, if a session is started with:

```
$ sbt ~run
```

and the server starts in development mode, and then in another terminal window another `sbt` session is started (to run another subproject, or just to run other `sbt` tasks), this second `sbt` session will update the `BuildInfo.scala` file, and the first `sbt` session will detect this and reload the Play project.

So the question is how to exclude `BuildInfo.scala` from monitoring (but still compile it and include it in the distribution package).

Apparently the `watchSources` configuration option could help, but after reading the documentation I couldn't figure out how to use it to exclude a file.

Comment: Have you tried `watchSources := watchSources.value.filter { _.getName != "BuildInfo.scala" }` ? I tried to reproduce basic setup, and for me the `BuildInfo.scala` file is not watched (you can check your setup by `show watchSources`).

Comment: I was able to filter a file out of watchSources with: `val myProject = play.Project(/*etc*/).settings(/*etc*/ watchSources := watchSources.value.filter { _.getName != "FileName.scala" })`. Your hint to use `show watchSources` also helped. I suggest you enter that as an answer and I'll approve it. It answers what I asked in this question, but it doesn't solved my problem, because I found out that `BuildInfo.scala` is not in `watchSources` (it is in `src_managed/`, which is not in `watchSources`), so the project must be restarting for another reason when I open the second session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove a particular file from being watched you can do in `build.sbt`:

```
watchSources := watchSources.value.filter { _.getName != "BuildInfo.scala" }
```

I tried to reproduce basic setup, and for me the BuildInfo.scala file is not watched. You can see the list of watched sources by issuing `show watchSources`.

Comment: So, how to exclude a folder so Play Framework won't watch any files in that folder for changes?

Comment: To exclude the whole folder from being watched, you can use
watchSources := (watchSources.value --- baseDirectory.value / "your-folder-here" ** "*").get